# Any file (image, etc.) is saving but showing 0 KB only. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to save my confusion matrix plot with different names for each model in a loop. But the extracted file were 0 KB and also had no extension for the file. And when I want to save my model as pickle, it also 0KB. But, my plot was showed right. Here's example of the plot in python notebook:

[image: example of plot in python notebook]

Here's the example of the saved file:

[image: example output file]

I already try to change the device to run code, add plt.clf() in beginning, put .show() not before saving it, and it still produce the same error. Now, I had no idea how to fix it.

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thanks.

```
def gbc_gscv_modelling(data, features, grid, title):
y = data.label
X = data[features]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=18)

gbc_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=gbc(random_state=42), param_grid=grid, cv=5, n_jobs=15, verbose=4)

gbc_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(gbc_cv.best_params_)

y_pred = gbc_cv.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
print(f"Precision: {precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'):.3f}")
print(f"Recall: {recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'):.3f}")
plt.clf()
cm = plot_confusion_matrix(gbc_cv.best_estimator_, X=x_test, y_true=y_test, labels=gbc_cv.classes_, cmap='Blues')
cm.figure_.suptitle(title)
cm.figure_.savefig(title+'.png')
cm.figure_.show()

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, output_dict=True)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
avg_precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
avg_recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
precision_sit = report.get("sit").get("precision")
precision_jog = report.get("jog").get("precision")
precision_dws = report.get("dws").get("precision")
precision_ups = report.get("ups").get("precision")
precision_std = report.get("std").get("precision")
precision_wlk = report.get("wlk").get("precision")
recall_sit = report.get("sit").get("recall")
recall_jog = report.get("jog").get("recall")
recall_dws = report.get("dws").get("recall")
recall_ups = report.get("ups").get("recall")
recall_std = report.get("std").get("recall")
recall_wlk = report.get("wlk").get("recall")

df_result = pd.DataFrame([accuracy, avg_precision, avg_recall, precision_sit, precision_jog, precision_dws, \
       precision_ups, precision_std, precision_wlk, recall_sit, recall_jog, \
       recall_dws, recall_ups, recall_std, recall_wlk])
return df_result
```

I don't know why this chunk of code not functioning properly on my code...

```
...
cm.figure_.savefig(title+'.png')
...
```

Comment: Maybe there is no free space in that partition? This would explain empty files for both pyplot and pickle.

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to show the actual code you want to ask about. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Comment: You are using the plot `title` as the name of the file, but your title clearly has invalid characters as file name: `:` is not a valid character in a windows file name. Test your code with a simpler file name and it should work.